# Can we Prove without wolfram that $\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac12 \log\frac{x^2-x+1}{x^2+x+1}=-3.985527186 \times 10^{-16}$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, definite-integrals, numerical-calculus

While calculating an another integral, I had to calculate the following integral

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^2-1}{x^4+x^2+1}dx$$

Indefinite integral of above function yields $$\frac12 \log\frac{x^2-x+1}{x^2+x+1}$$

Plotting the function $\frac12 \log\frac{x^2-x+1}{x^2+x+1}$ on desmos, I can see that it is exactly $0$ at $x=0$ (As given function cuts $x$-axis at origin) but it is $\to 0$ as $x\to \infty$.

[image]

Wolfram says Integral is about
$-3.985527186 \times 10^{-16}$.That means It the limit of the function $\frac12 \log\frac{x^2-x+1}{x^2+x+1}$
at $x=\infty$

[image]

> My question is How can we prove without wolfram that $$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac12 \log\frac{x^2-x+1}{x^2+x+1}=-3.985527186 \times 10^{-16}$$

Comment: That limit is just $\frac{1}{2}$. Both logarithms behave like $\log(x^2)=2\log x$ for large $x$, so their ratio tends to $1$. Can you see it?

Comment: Using L'Hopital?

Comment: @Gary Then How is the integral $-3.985527186 \times 10^{-16}$

Comment: It is certainly not that: Wolfram Alpha has used numerical integration which creates a floating-point error.

Comment: $\log\frac ab$ or $\frac{\log a}{\log b}$ ?? And don't you think that such a value is completely unlikely ?

Comment: It is $0$: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate+%28x%5E2-1%29%2F%28x%5E4%2Bx%5E2%2B1%29+from+0+to+infinity And the indefinite integral is the difference of the logarithms and not the ratio of them. $\log a-\log b \neq \log a / \log b$ but rather $\log(a/b)$.

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+%28x%5E2-1%29%2F%28x%5E4%2Bx%5E2%2B1%29+from+0+to+infinity) says the answer is $0$ with the correct antiderivative.

Comment: So Is That an error by wolfram?

Comment: @User9868689 Can you see why that limit must be $0$?

Comment: The number $\sim 10^{-16}$ is the [machine epsilon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon) (the numerical precision) of standard (64 bit) floating point numbers. Whenever you see it in a numerical calculation its very likely the result is $0$, but that numerical errors leads to a finite result.

Comment: @TobyMak= WA's behavior is unexpected here. When just entering the integrand, it evaluates from $0$ to $\infty$ numerically, and when asking for more decimals, eventually concludes $\approx0$. But he computes analytically with https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+%28x%5E2-1%29%2F%28x%5E4%2Bx%5E2%2B1%29+from+0+to+infinity

Comment: @Gary Yes. Thank you

Comment: The command of Mathematica 12.3 `Integrate[(x^2 - 1)/(x^4 + x^2 + 1), {x, 0, Infinity}]` outputs $0$ as well as W|A Pro (input integral instead of integrate).

Comment: As a sidenote, calculating the integral via antiderivative might have been a bit too much effort, but nothing wrong with an antiderivative of course. The variable interchange $x \leftrightarrow \frac{1}{x}$ shows that $I=-I$ right off the bat.

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align} 
\lim_{x\to \infty}
\ln\frac{x^2-x+1}{x^2+x+1}
&=
\lim_{x\to \infty}
\ln\left(
\frac{x^3+1}{x^3-1}
\cdot
\frac{x-1}{x+1}
\right)
\\
&=\lim_{x\to \infty}
\ln\left(\frac{x^3+1}{x^3-1}\right)
+\lim_{x\to \infty}\ln\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)
\\
&=\lim_{x\to \infty}
\ln\left(\frac{1+\tfrac1{x^3}}{1-\tfrac1{x^3}}\right)
+\lim_{x\to \infty}\ln\left(\frac{1-\tfrac1x}{1+\tfrac1x}\right)
=0
.
\end{align}

Or just

\begin{align} 
\lim_{x\to \infty}
\ln\frac{x^2-x+1}{x^2+x+1}
&=
\lim_{x\to \infty}
\ln\left(
1-\frac{2x}{x^2+x+1}
\right)
\\
&=
\lim_{x\to \infty}
\ln\left(
1-\frac{2}{x+1+\tfrac1x}
\right)
=0
.
\end{align}

Comment: You just split things up but the fractions in the second part are not easier to calculate than the fraction at the beginning. You then could just say that the linear terms are not relevant.

Comment: @LegNaiB: is it more clear now?

Comment: Why bother with $x^3$? $\log\frac{1-x^{-1}+x^{-2}}{1+x^{-1}+x^{-2}}$ is a much shorter way.

Comment: @metamorphy: you are absolutely right. It must be a reflex.

Comment: Why not simply divide both numerator and denominator with $x^2$?

Comment: @Ritam_Dasgupta: yes, this works too.

Answer (score 2):

We could just use l'Hopital's rule to evaluate the limit:
$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to \infty}
\ln\frac{x^2-x+1}{x^2+x+1}
&=\ln\left(\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{x^2-x+1}{x^2+x+1}\right)\\
&=\ln\left(\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{2x-1}{2x+1}\right)\\
&=\ln\left(\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{2}{2}\right)=\ln1=0.\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: You don't need l'Hopital's rule: just work on equivalents $\dfrac{x^2-x+1}{x^2+x+1} \approx \dfrac{x^2}{x^2}=1$.

Comment: @JeanMarie How do you know that without L'Hopital's rule?

Comment: Because a polynomial $p(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1 }+...$ is equivalent when $x \to \infty$ to its highest degree monomial $a_nx^n$ .

Answer (score 0):

$$I(t)=\int_{0}^{t}\frac{x^2-1}{x^4+x^2+1}dx=\frac12 \log\left(\frac{t^2-t+1}{t^2+t+1}\right)=\frac12 \log\left(\frac{1-\frac 1t+\frac 1 {t^2} }{1-\frac 1t+\frac 1 {t^2} }\right)$$
$$I(t)=-\frac{1}{t}+\frac{2}{3 t^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{t^5}\right)$$